# How can add swiping grid content into my site?

Tags: jquery

I came across this site (http://wearehunted.com/ipad/index.html) that seems to use some jquery to arrange its content into changeable grids in landscape and portrait and allows the user to swipe left and right through the content on a ipad instead of scrolling. Is there a plugin available that does something like this?

Comment: Possibly... have you tried searching?  sorry for sounding a bit rude... but people will not go out and do the research for you...Find a plugin that you feel suites you... try it out...and if then you have a problem come and post it here including things you have tried and what problems you faced.

Comment: Have a look through the jQuery mobile documentation, that should get you started.